# Flutter - open popup or bottomSheet via Navigator pushNamed()

Tags: flutter

I tried to open bottomSheet via routes.
Is there some chance to opet bottomSheet or popup via Navigator.pushNamed(..)?

```
onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {


      if(!_user.isLoggedIn()){
      //HERE I NEED SHOW BOTTOM SHEET 
      }         

      switch (settings.name) {

        //* HOME ---------------------------------------------
        case Routes.home:
          return SimplePageRoute(
            builder: (context) => HomeScreen(),
            settings: RouteSettings(name: Routes.home),
          );
          break;

        //another routes...

      }
    },
```

Comment: why would you do that ?
do you want to open the bottomsheet whenever the user click on a button or something ??

Comment: Yes I want use bottomSheet modal for sign in. I am using pushNamed with routes and I need show bottomSheet in onGenerateRoute method like this
`onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
 // some logic..
 // here I need show bottomSheetModal when user is logged out
}`

Comment: if you want the bottomSheet just call it in onClick method
    onTap: (){
       bottomSheet(context);
     },
but if you call the route first you will navigate to the other page and will not lunch the bottomsheet ..

Comment: No, I have some secure conditions in onGenerateRoute, where calling all of request, and when the user doesn't have a right permission I need open bottomSheet. There is no specific element to clicking.

Comment: can you please show me the code

Comment: Ok I am updated the question with code

Comment: @PetrKlein how did you solved that?